# Arduino Getting Data From Web Page

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to connect my Arduino uno + Ethernet shield to a php script that gets a value from a database and then is sent back which then is displayed on a serial monitor. It works, it connects successfully and i get the value sent back however I'm having trouble displaying it on the serial monitor. It should just display what the server sends however it doesn't. Any one can help?

The Serial Output : It should just output "The Value", however there are numbers that shouldn't be there. If i output this to a LCD monitor i can't have them numbers present.

```
connecting...
connected
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2014 15:36:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dcef101052b82760c1a2de019e6b076141388849811461; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.linku.biz; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.27
CF-RAY: e7901b6dec606e2

4
The 
5
Value
0


disconnecting.
```

PHP Script

```
<?php
echo 'The Value';
?>
```

Arduino Script

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };


char server[] = "www.linku.biz";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /arduino.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.linku.biz");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available 
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this helps, but notice that the numbers are the count of available chars which are read out. 4 "The " and 5 "value"

I would expect that client.available returns the 4 and 5 values just after those chars are received. How they got converted to ASCI "4" and "5" and printed, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I parse data by this code

```
String readString;

   //gets byte from ethernet buffer
    readString += client.read(); //places captured byte in 

 //parse readString for request
    index = readString.indexOf("text"); //finds location of first "text"
    data_want = readString.substring(index+some char, index+some char); //captures data String

    Serial.println(data_wand);
```